# Android SQLite Beginner Error

Tags: android, sqlite

Just a real quick question, probably something really simple but I've never done ANYTHING with databases before, can someone tell me why the second line is giving me an error?

Thank you! :)

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS index (ChalNum INT(3));");
```

**ERROR:**

```
ERROR: 02-12 05:21:47.573: E/AndroidRuntime(1199): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.Home}: 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Index": syntax error (code 1): ,
 while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Index (ChalNum INT(3));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use the `Index` name for the Table. Its a keyword for SQLite.

Try out with `Index1` or some other name.

Besides using exact word `Index` use `Index1` as below:

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Index1 (ChalNum INT(3));");
```

Answer (score 3):

`INDEX` is a SQLite keyword. Choose a different name for your table.

Answer (score -1):

You will like to use:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS index1 (ChalNum INTEGER);");
```

Emil